# mydomain->GMail Ok, GMail->mydomain = snailmail

Tags: exchange-2013, gmail, barracuda

General context :

In France

ISP : Completel/SFR (something casual)

Server Exchange 2013

Barracuda 300

Quite often, about 8/10, mails from Gmail arrive on our server with a huge delay, 11 hours this time.

Here's some headers :

```
Received: from MES-02.nutri.local (2002:c004:dd3::c004:dd3) by
 MES-02.nutri.local (2002:c004:dd3::c004:dd3) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS)
 id 15.0.1293.2 via Mailbox Transport; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 21:04:37 +0200
Received: from MES-02.nutri.local (2002:c004:dd5::c004:dd5) by
 MES-02.nutri.local (2002:c004:dd5::c004:dd5) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS)
 id 15.0.1293.2; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 21:04:26 +0200
Received: from barracuda.mydomain.fr (192.4.13.249) by MES-02.nutri.local
 (192.4.13.211) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 15.0.1293.2 via Frontend
 Transport; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 21:04:26 +0200
X-ASG-Debug-ID: 1506366186-0d0e1e108216f820001-ga6i4b
Received: from mail-oi0-f44.google.com (mail-oi0-f44.google.com [209.85.218.44]) by barracuda.mydomain.fr with ESMTP id RwbNnxEIffvuOeoq for <me@mydomain.fr>; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 21:03:06 +0200 (CEST)
X-Barracuda-Envelope-From: me@gmail.com
X-Barracuda-Effective-Source-IP: mail-oi0-f44.google.com[209.85.218.44]
X-Barracuda-Apparent-Source-IP: 209.85.218.44
X-Barracuda-User-Whitelist: me@mydomain.fr
Received: by mail-oi0-f44.google.com with SMTP id r20so8449350oie.0
        for <me@mydomain.fr>; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 12:03:06 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=101hk4XXS8wkNTIWAxt3MC8m34P5hCl31RchaG6seM0=;
        b=IC7CdJVSlzouSKuGIt42+RSwzDLM8gNDhZJDShFFWI613VWrXC8rV9l/QtHqdIeocM
         SUMr4SldHRlBW1UCDm83SyhlkhWace52np3Pm9TjDaxDJRcdtOJEhf0oIuiLUBPTG/xA
         8JiyHxtFiE0dH8dF+QH75p2/CfMZhoU3MXwf/2zsJG4Qo43a6tl/47860WFF+r5SzM0k
         dj5RUUF6/SrBSc+F+UGu1TwmfOw/h07qfK95cUuw3prtw5i17Sq1jEdssXAif/FjN+tQ
         I4aGmZxOYmlecTyxOzQFIUgVtYpyJrEdV2o18H0aMEP25Xp9p4wYZzzRS76PlLMO6aPj
         a1FA==
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20161025;
        h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:from:date:message-id:subject:to;
        bh=101hk4XXS8wkNTIWAxt3MC8m34P5hCl31RchaG6seM0=;
        b=P0xZc+lGT4OIayfe6Zqwe7RJSW6EBQJWVk2AMSpAOipMwQVSdyCnozLdLltis9+pmP
         ByTdBkBo8CGdLaZBpqpXToBMGUUjLph3zBEn1EpWTuEZNnGogAL5KyaiNU3NU+vV9B6p
         e1Q+T16BASZKyY9qLqBokNtqB9g+WJ8vpPJXkvxCSKqFKrdRP0ysKnVIAiEcRbuGdmNZ
         0Q2oIZLarFYUeK4aeTZQJb4ThViz4xdWCa8mXxJgNC8mMmnOfS2CIXxIg94qHnUsz4a2
         s00RE1CQ7JwktYEa+VxuKE8eVgGx+6GqEo23BneRZde0CrIO0EHb4p29tW6pvgqgrg64
         SfJw==
X-Gm-Message-State: AHPjjUi5m4CGwk1Y35749OmQqHzDhfuNvCO0PJ6eEYE++iSEvZRKIil5
    p2zjF8JtNvF3fSU+fxakPPeY/3iMWXCYJ5wLsRk=
X-Google-Smtp-Source: AOwi7QDz8/EQaHA6s1eBYIokK60fVzXpZTOEs+XyQVBFICmN4B3B1UMHOfEhE2frsShPRTreSwfbNU/z2x8h6/5S9r4=
X-Received: by 10.202.66.10 with SMTP id p10mr8628072oia.211.1506326236015;
 Mon, 25 Sep 2017 00:57:16 -0700 (PDT)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.74.174.8 with HTTP; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 00:57:11 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.74.174.8 with HTTP; Mon, 25 Sep 2017 00:57:11 -0700 (PDT)
From: Emmanuel Valou <me@gmail.com>
Date: Mon, 25 Sep 2017 09:57:11 +0200
Message-ID: <CAKtqvW=1yn2=opFpV-xtobHv3L0CoU0k24x4iDnHvffYN6y-NA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Vp
To: me@mydomain.fr
X-ASG-Orig-Subj: Vp
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="001a113dde7e3837200559fee8c5"
X-Barracuda-Connect: mail-oi0-f44.google.com[209.85.218.44]
X-Barracuda-Start-Time: 1506366186
X-Barracuda-URL: https://antispam.mydomain.fr:443/cgi-mod/mark.cgi
X-Virus-Scanned: by bsmtpd at mydomain.fr
X-Barracuda-Scan-Msg-Size: 26
X-Barracuda-BRTS-Status: 1
Return-Path: me@gmail.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id: f1bb64ed-9fb3-4ff8-1905-08d504483ec9
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Enterprise: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: MES-02.nutri.local
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
```

mxtoolbox tells me the issue is between our Barracuda and Gmail.

But, to solve the issue, is it something WE have to do or Google has to do ?

And what ?

Answer (score 0):

Google will do nothing - they will probably ignore you if you attempted to contact them - there is nothing wrong with Google's email delivery platform. The problem is at your end.

You need to find the log in Barracuda for the delivery attempt and see why it failed. If there is no trace of delivery attempt until the 11 hours then I would be looking at an issue outside of your network.

All MX Toolbox has told you is that there was a delivery delay - it doesn't tell you the cause, because the headers will not.